# (SBT) How to disable default resolver and only use the company internal resolver?

Tags: scala, sbt, nexus, artifactory

We want to use company internal ivy/maven repository (artifactory) to improve the speed of resolving, and downloading the jar files, and also we want to use it to exchange binary jar files between different teams in our organization.

I know we can force SBT to go through proxy by setting `~/.repositories` with

```
[repositories]
  local
  my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://repo.alpinenow.com/artifactory/repo/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  my-maven-proxy-releases: http://repo.alpinenow.com/artifactory/repo/
```

and then launch SBT with `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true`. This method works for me.

However, it's kind of cumbersome to ask all the developers to setup this way. We're wondering if we can override the default resolvers completely in Build.scala, and plugin.sbt without extra configuration.

So far, I've tried the following ways without success.

1) In both Build.scala and plugin.sbt, I added

```
resolvers := "Local Repo" at "http://repo.alpinenow.com/artifactory/repo/",

externalResolvers := Seq(Resolver.url("Local Repo", url("http://repo.alpinenow.com/artifactory/repo"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)),
```

but it still downloads the jars from typesafe and maven1.

2) I then decided to put repositories file into project folder, and tried to add java option directly inside plugin.sbt, and Build.scala with

```
System.setProperty("-Dsbt.override.build.repos", "true"),

System.setProperty("-Dsbt.repository.config", "project/repositories"),
```

but it still doesn't work. I'm curious when the SBT gets the java options for resolvers since obviously, it's before plugin.sbt and Build.scala.

Any idea?

Thanks.

DB Tsai

Comment: According to the offical documentation, shouldn't your repository config be in `~/.sbt/repositories`, not `~/.repositories` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you depart from the [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) shell script as a replacement for the default launcher script, I guess you could easily modify that with setting up `~/.repositories` and adding `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true`. Then all you need to do is ensure your developers use that script.

Comment: Yeah. If I can not find a way to do it just in Build.scala etc, I probably will replace the default launcher script. But it's the last way I will do.

Comment: In this end, we use this as our solution. Thanks.

Comment: where do you set `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` ? In a file or as an sbt parameter?

Comment: @pedromss if I remember correctly, that's a parameter for sbt. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779973/how-to-make-dsbt-override-build-repos-true-global-for-sbt#29780347

Answer (score 6):

## Project level

According to the documentation we should be using `externalResolvers`:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Overriding+default+resolvers

```
externalResolvers := Seq(
  "Local Repo" at "http://repo.alpinenow.com/artifactory/repo/",
  // some more internal Nexus repositories
)
```

## Plugin level

You'll have to do it also in your `project` folder for plugins like in `project/resolvers.sbt`.

## Global SBT level

And if you also want SBT it self to resolve from a specific repo, you'll need to do as described here:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

I am always adding SBT build as part of my repo in SVN/GIT, close with code. Then I have no such problems.

It costs about 1MB space so is quite cheap and solves a lot of problems.  All developers use identical build tool. Even if I try to create Continues Integration or more advanced Continues Delivery process all SBT configs will be already well configured in my SCM. I will get one source of true :)