# How to make -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true global for SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to override all repos even the ones introduced inadvertently in my `build.sbt` files so we can point to our proxy and have a common binary base for all the team. The option

```
$ sbt -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
```

does the job but I'd like to make this option permanent. I've been looking at http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Global-Settings.html but I don't know how to translate that option to the `global.sbt` file they mention.

How would you configure that option globally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` to the `SBT_OPTS` environment variable

Comment: I was looking to something that should be enforced by de Continuous Integration machine but your answer pointed me to the fact that at least in Ubuntu if you install SBT using the package manager you have the file `/etc/sbt-launcher-packaging/sbtopts` where you can insert the command and now it works for all users of that machine.

Comment: In recent versions of sbt, you may place the above property definition to your project's `.sbtopts`.

Answer (score -1):

When running on windows, it can be defined in the file sbtconfig.txt under <SBT_HOME>/bin :

```
-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
```

You can create this file if you don't have it already

Comment: `sbtconfig.txt` is a Windows-only configuration file. It would be nice to mention that in your answer, @mhdkassir